# ReactiveMongo with Akka Streams Custom Source

Tags: scala, akka-stream, reactivemongo

I am using reactivemongo-akka-stream and trying to transform the `AkkaStreamCursor.documentSource`. I am and am seeing two problems:

1. the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/streaming.html#akka-stream) states that this operation returns a `Source[T, NotUsed]` but `collection.find(query).cursor[BSONDocument].doccumentSource()` returns a `Source[BSONDocument, Future[State]]`. Is there a way to avoid the State object?
2. Assuming I use `Future[State]` I am looking to get source of class as below

   ```
   case class Inner(foo: String, baz: Int)

   case class Outer(bar: Inner)

   //
   implicit object InnerReader extends BSONDocumentReader[Inner]//defined

   val getCollection: Future[BSONCollection] = connection.database("db").map(_.collection("things")

   def stream()(implicit m: Materializer): Source[Outer, Future[State]] = {
    getCollection.map(_.find().cursor[Inner]().documentSource()).map(_.via(Flow[Inner].map(in => Outer(in))))
   ```

But instead of getting back a `Future[Source[Outer, Future[State]]` that i could deal with, this returns a `Future[Source[Inner, Future[State]]#Repr[Outer]]`

How can bson readers be used with this library?

Comment: The first example in the linked doc uses `Future[State]`. If you don't care about the materialisation state, then dont use it. Then that's not theresponsibility of the BSON readers to deal with async concerns. To flatten source of Future you can use flatMapConcat and fromFuture, or since Akka 2.5.1 Source.fromFutureGraph .

Comment: What did you mean by BSON dealing with async concerns?  I just want to stream into a custom case class... I am not quite understanding the type signature with `#Repr[Outer]`

Comment: Have you tried the suggested `flatMapConcat` or `fromFutureGraph` solutions? (such `Repr` dependent type is common with Akka Stream).

Answer (score 1):

As per the suggestion by cchantep, I needed to use `fromFuture` with `flatMapConcat`:

```
def stream()(implicit m: Materializer): Source[Outer, NotUsed] = {
 val foo = getCollection.map(x => col2Source(x))

 fix(foo).via(flowmap(map = Outer(_)))
}
def col2Source(col: BSONCollection): Source[Inner, Future[State]] = {
 val cursor: AkkaStreamCursor[Inner] = 
   col.find(BSONDocument.empty).cursor[Inner]()

 cursor.documentSource()
}

def flowmap[In, Out](
 map: (In) => Out
): Flow[In, Out, NotUsed] = Flow[In].map(e => map(e))

def fix[Out, Mat](futureSource: Future[Source[Out, Mat]]): Source[Out, NotUsed] = {
 Source.fromFuture(futureSource).flatMapConcat(identity)
}
```